# Error occured during initialization of the VM

Tags: java, maven, jvm

I lanched the command `mvn -version` just after reboot and I got:

```
Apache Maven 3.3.1 (cab6659f9874fa96462afef40fcf6bc033d58c1c; 2015-03-13T21:10:2
7+01:00)
Maven home: C:\apache-maven-3.3.1\bin\..
Java version: 1.7.0_45, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre
Default locale: fr_FR, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 8", version: "6.2", arch: "x86", family: "windows"
```

and then lanched on my directory project the command:

```
  mvn -o clean install
```

and I got

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

After when I rexecute the command "mvn -version" I got the same error
Any ideas why I got this strange behavior and how can I fix it? 
I already set the Maven variable:

```
 MAVEN_OPTS = -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

There is a quotation mark on the end of the line?

```
MAVEN_OPTS = -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m"
```

Comment: Actually this is just typo, the quotation mark does not exist in my environment variable. I also edited the question, I actually got the error after trying to build my project.

Answer (score 0):

The error message means that you have not enough RAM to run the JVM with your requested memory settings. Probably after booting there are not many other applications running and so there are 1.5 GB RAM left, but after a while with additional programs running the requested 1.5 GB RAM are not accessible anymore. Try reducing your setting, e.g. to:

```
MAVEN_OPTS = -Xmx256m -XX:MaxPermSize=64m
```

This should be enough for running `maven -version`.